# Enclose frontmatter value using double quotes in 11ty files after an edit and publish in netlify cms

Tags: yaml, netlify-cms, eleventy

I'm using 11ty with netlify cms,

```
---
title: "sample title"
description: "sample description"
canonical: "https://www.example.com"
---
```

the above is the frontmatter data in my 11ty files. when I edit the files using netlify cms and publish it, the double quotes are removed as shown below,

```
---
title: sample title
description: sample description
canonical: https://www.example.com
---
```

I want that quotes not to be removed because in some files, the values in frontmatter contain punctuation marks like 'colon' so it will cause yaml syntax exception if the value is not enclosed in quotes.

while entering the title in netlify cms, if i enter as "sample title" with the double quotes, it is written to the file as,

```
title: '"sample title"'
```

I want just the double quotes after editing using netlify cms like shown below,

```
---
title: "sample title"
description: "sample description"
canonical: "https://www.example.com"
---
```

Could anyone suggest me a way to do it? Thanks in advance...